# How to Change(tick) Validation Hints of Password while typing Password?

Tags: javascript, c#, validation

I am trying to validate the password on client side while typing, by changing the the password hints valid with respect to given password. On the coding/server side, I added the validation already and its working too. In the Client side, I want to alert user using hints.

Example only that how I want:

[image: Image of What I want to Change while typing Password].

I want to change the glyphicon remove icon into OK once it satisfies the validations of the password. This is just an instruction to the user that tell them their password can be valid or not.

Code below:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold ; color:navy;">
 Password Hint:
</div>
<div class="row" style=" color:black; margin:10px 0px">   
<span id="Length" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-weight:bold;color:red "></span> &nbsp; Minimum 6 digits
<br /><span id="UpperCase" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-weight:bold;color:red "></span> &nbsp;Atleast 1 upper case letters (A – Z)
<br /><span id="LowerCase" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-weight:bold;color:red "></span>&nbsp; Atleast 1 Lower case letters (a – z)
<br /><span id="Numbers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-weight:bold;color:red "></span> &nbsp;Atleast 1 number (0 – 9)
<br /><span id="Symbols" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-weight:bold;color:red "></span>&nbsp; Atleast 1 non-alphanumeric symbol (e.g. ‘@@Z$%£!’)
</div>
```

Script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function () {
        $("#NewPassword").bind("keyup", function () {
         var regex1 = new Array();
        var regex2 = new Array();
        var regex3 = new Array();
        var regex4 = new Array();
            regex1.push("[A-Z]"); //Uppercase Alphabet.
            regex2.push("[a-z]"); //Lowercase Alphabet.
            regex3.push("[0-9]"); //Digit.
            regex4.push("[!@@#$%^&*]"); //Special Character.

         if ($(this).val().length<6) {
                $('#Length').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok ");              
            }

        for (var i = 0; i < regex1.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#UpperCase').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok ");
                }
            }
         for (var i = 0; i < regex2.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#LowerCase').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
                }
            }
         for (var i = 0; i < regex3.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#Numbers').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
                }
            }
         for (var i = 0; i < regex4.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#Symbols').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
                }
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

My password textbox id is "NewPassword". But my above coding does not work. I got display only, but not working.

Comment: What happens if you put a console.log function inside your event handler? Does it write anything out to the console? Just checking if your handler is running.

Comment: sory I dont understand what u r saying as I am new to MVC I tried using google and everything only. Also I got confused whether my coding got correct or not?

Comment: So in your keyup event handler, just before you define your array variables, put a console.log('test'); line. When you start typing in your password field, do you see 'test' in the console window in your browsers dev tools?

Comment: I added that line as per ur comment - but no console window comeout when I am typing..mentioned  below     
       $("#NewPassword").bind("keyup", function () {
        **console.log('test');**
         var regex1 = new Array();
        var regex2 = new Array();
        var regex3 = new Array();
        var regex4 = new Array();
       .

Comment: Just updated my answer with a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just a typo in your javascript. Each time you loop through one of your arrays you're referencing regex[i] instead of regex1[i], or which ever array your looping through.

I've tweaked the styling slightly, just to get it working locally.

```
<div class="row" style=" color:black; margin:10px 0px">
        <p id="Length" class="alert alert-danger">Minimum 6 digits</p>
        <p id="UpperCase" class="alert alert-danger">At least 1 upper case letters (A – Z)</p>
        <p id="LowerCase" class="alert alert-danger"> At least 1 Lower case letters (a – z)</p>
        <p id="Numbers" class="alert alert-danger">At least 1 number (0 – 9)</p>
        <p id="Symbols" class="alert alert-danger"> At least 1 non-alphanumeric symbol (e.g. ‘@@Z$%£!’)</p>
    </div>
```

This is the javascript just after the regex variables have been set.

```
$('p.alert').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');

            if ($(this).val().length<6) {
                $('#Length').removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < regex1.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex1[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#UpperCase').removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < regex2.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex2[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#LowerCase').removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < regex3.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex3[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#Numbers').removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < regex4.length; i++) {
                if (new RegExp(regex4[i]).test($(this).val())) {
                    $('#Symbols').removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console when you load the page?